# Face Detection real-time with Local Binary Pattern

Tags: image-processing, python, computer-vision

I'm writing for code to detect human face by Local Binary Pattern algorithm in webcam, but with my limited knowledge in optimization code, I having to struggle in detect in each frame , I want to say that I used haar-cascade but my teacher say is prohibited. So I have to browse through each window ([45x45]) on every frame, but none to say, it not work . I really need your help or any sugggestion for my problem. Thank you so much for spent time for this.

And this is my SVM file already trained before: https://file.io/TTrTW3ow4LG9

So this is my code:

```py
import cv2
import os
import sys
import  time
import numpy as np
import joblib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import shutil
import glob
from skimage import data, color, feature
import skimage.data


cv2.namedWindow('frame', cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)  


scale_factor = 2.0
size, center_x = 0,0
fps = 0 
frame_counter = 0
start_time = time.time()

dataset_folder = "D:/download/"

model = joblib.load(dataset_folder + "best_model (2) .pkl")      

fps = 0 
frame_counter = 0
start_time = time.time()

def _check(test_image):
    indices, patches = zip(*sliding_window(test_image))
    patches_hog = np.array([feature.hog(patch) for patch in patches])
    
    npoint = 8
    rad = 1.0
    patches_hog = []
    for im in patches:
        # Compute LBP features
        lbp_feature = feature.local_binary_pattern(im, npoint, rad)
        lbp_feature = np.histogram(lbp_feature.ravel(), bins=np.arange(0, npoint + 3), range=(0, npoint + 2))
        lbp_feature = lbp_feature[0]
        
        hog_feature = feature.hog(im)
        
        concatenated_feature = np.concatenate((hog_feature, lbp_feature))
        result = model.predict_proba([concatenated_feature])
        
        patches_hog.append(concatenated_feature)

    
    patches_hog = np.array(patches_hog)
    labels = model.predict(patches_hog)
    
    Ni, Nj = (45, 45)
    indices = np.array(indices)
    
    
    for i, j in indices[labels == 1]:
        ax.add_patch(plt.Rectangle((j, i), Nj, Ni, edgecolor='red',
                                   alpha=0.3, lw=2, facecolor='none'))

    

    
def sliding_window(img, patch_size=(45,45),
                   istep=2, jstep=2, scale=1.0):
    Ni, Nj = (int(scale * s) for s in patch_size)
    for i in range(0, img.shape[0] - Ni, istep):
        for j in range(0, img.shape[1] - Ni, jstep):
            patch = img[i:i + Ni, j:j + Nj]
            if scale != 1:
                patch = transform.resize(patch, patch_size)
            yield (i, j), patch

while True: 
    # Read a frame from the camera
    ret, img = cap.read()
    frame_counter += 1
    img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) 
    _check(img)
    cv2.imshow('Capture Faces', img)
 
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
 
# Release the camera and close windows
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```